# Any other ways to slide Side menu?

Tags: codenameone

Currently we have side menu which when it opens, it makes the form slide in the corner too like in fb app. I wonder if we can slide the side menu on top of the form itself like in play store or many other app which is way cool.

Answer (score 0):

That's a frequently asked feature and we hope to add it in the near future although we have a very deep pipeline of RFE's so I'm not sure when we will get around to doing it.

Comment: Hello, I've 1 more question related to it. If I write the codes in native android and build through CN1 using NativeInterface. Will that code work for iOS as well?

Comment: It will work if you implement the iOS objective-c side of that too